# Outer Div the Width of it's content when it has inline-block elements inside

Tags: html, css, inline

So I have a wrapper div that I want to be the width of it's content inside. I've read that the best way to do that is to make it `display: inline-block;` The issue is, that doesn't work when I have a bunch of inline-block elements inside the div. Any way to fix this?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bq37actj/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrap">
  <h1>Heading</h1>

    <div class="item">
      <h2>Item 1</h2>
      <p>Details</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h2>Item 1</h2>
      <p>Details</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h2>Item 1</h2>
      <p>Details</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h2>Item 1</h2>
      <p>Details</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.inner-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Try to use display:flex

Comment: @Amit that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Using `inline-flex` instead of `inline-block` will make the inner wrapper scale to its children:

```css
.inner-wrap {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: that put all of the items on one line.

Comment: You can set the container to wrap its children using `flex-wrap: wrap;`. If you want to have more control over the amount of items per line, edit their `flex` property i.e. `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`. CSS-Tricks provides a [good intro to flex boxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you want to learn more.

Comment: I'm not sure which end result you want, but [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bq37actj/14/) is an example to show you the possibilities of flex boxes, something less chaotic.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want .inner-wrap to be the width of the widest .item ?
If so, then 
    .item{display:block;width:auto;}